# How to write async function a module function using fat arrow notation

Tags: javascript, async-await, node-modules

I want to write a **module** similar to the one below.

It should be callable via "Server.doBackup" and use the **fat arrow notation** together with an **async-await** function

Any ideas?
**Can you provide a corrected version of my snippet below?**

```
const Server = {
  config: {
    documents: ['DEFAULT', 'KEYS'],
    exportpath: 'data/exportFromCosmos/',
    uploadpath: 'data/uploadToAzureBlob/',
    crosscheckFile: 'data/crosscheckFile.txt'
  },
  doBackup: () => async {
    let prepareFolders = await Folders.prepare(Server.config, resolve)
    let downloadDB_DEFAULT = await Database.downloadDocumentsOfType_DEFAULT()
    let downloadDB_KEYS = await Database.downloadDocumentsOfType_KEYS()
    let zipDocuments = await Documents.zip(Server.config)
  }
}

module.exports = Server
```

Comment: Read about [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). The `async` keyword must stay in front of the function definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const Server = {
  config: {
    documents: ['DEFAULT', 'KEYS'],
    exportpath: 'data/exportFromCosmos/',
    uploadpath: 'data/uploadToAzureBlob/',
    crosscheckFile: 'data/crosscheckFile.txt'
  },
  doBackup: async () =>  {
    let prepareFolders = await Folders.prepare(Server.config, resolve)
    let downloadDB_DEFAULT = await Database.downloadDocumentsOfType_DEFAULT()
    let downloadDB_KEYS = await Database.downloadDocumentsOfType_KEYS()
    let zipDocuments = await Documents.zip(Server.config)
  }
}

module.exports = Server
```

// Sample Code

```js
async function findName(){
  return {name: "Stack"}
}

let user = {
  getName: async()=>{
    let {name} =  await findName()
    return name
  }
}

user.getName()
  .then((userDetail)=> console.log(userDetail))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```